# How to bind a SharePoint Multi-choice field to a WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, sharepoint, data-binding

I'm building a WPF MVVM application to interact with SharePoint list data. So far it's going ok, but I've run up against trying to deal with a multi-choice field. Sharepoint provides the data as an array of strings and I need to convert that to checkboxes.

I've been playing around with a conversion function with moderate success, but the ConvertBack function is not working at all. I have the field bound to three check boxes and have set a conversion parameter for each one to differentiate them. What I'm very unsure of is how to return back a string[] from the three checkboxes.

Here's the XAML for the fields:

```
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label>Correspondence</Label>
                        <CheckBox Name="chkP1Correspond" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Student.Parent_x0020_1_x0020_Mailing_x00, Converter={StaticResource mailingOptsBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=Correspondence}" Margin="5,6,0,0"/>
                        <Label>Scheduling</Label>
                        <CheckBox Name="chkP1Sched" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Student.Parent_x0020_1_x0020_Mailing_x00, Converter={StaticResource mailingOptsBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=Scheduling}" Margin="5,6,0,0"/>
                        <Label> Billing</Label>
                        <CheckBox Name="chkP1Bill" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Student.Parent_x0020_1_x0020_Mailing_x00, Converter={StaticResource mailingOptsBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=Billing}" Margin="5,6,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
```

Here's my Conversion function:

```
public class mailingOptsBoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string[] arrayValue = value as string[];
            string strParam = parameter as string;
            if (arrayValue is null)
            { return false; }
            else
            {

                if (Array.IndexOf(arrayValue, strParam) > -1)
                { return true; }
                else { return false; }
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool)
            {
                if ((bool)value == true)
                {
                    return (string)parameter;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Unsurprisingly, this doesn't work. The Convert function seems to function ok and it is rendering the checkboxes correctly. However, if I deselect one of the checkboxes, they all clear. Additionally, if I try to save the data back to Sharepoint, nothing gets updated. I'm pretty sure this is due to the ConvertBack function but I'm not entirely sure how to fix it.

Comment: The ConvertBack method of an IValueConverter must return a value that is assignable to the source property of the Binding, i.e. a `string[]` here. This isn't possible because it has no access to the "other" array elements. Consider creating a view model class that exposes the three CheckBox states as separate properties.

Comment: @Clemens thanks for the suggestion! So with that idea, would I then use a different control to put the three options together? If so, what control do you think would be appropriate?

Comment: No, you would just bind the three CheckBoxes to three different boolean properties.